# DrawerLayout in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, drawerlayout

I created DrawerLayot in my Windows Phone app with a help of library DrawerLayout.
All fine work in emulator., but when I run the application on my phone, he takes off. I noticed., this happens after the call Frame.Navigate(). what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Windows Phone 8.1 SDK issue. You can solve this problem by invoking the Dispatcher when you navigate to a page.

```
CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
      Frame.navigate(typeof(YourPage));
});
```

Comment: hello amar , from this code sloved the problem , but when I navigate morethan 3-4 times , application closed without any error code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919934/drawer-navigation-not-working-sometime-in-winodws-phone-8-1rt?noredirect=1#comment53669569_32919934

Comment: Could you elaborate on the SDK issue?