# Drawer Navigation not working sometime in Windows phone 8.1[RT]

Tags: xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, drawerlayout

I am working with Drawer layout found code from [msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-Now-its-b63049f9) 
I have six pages in my application and all page contains drawer , so I have to Initialize drawer in each page

```
 public page1() 
 {
    DrawerLayout.InitializeDrawerLayout();
    DrawerClass drawer = new DrawerClass();
    //contains drawer data , text and Image
    ListMenuItemsDrawer.ItemsSource = drawer.InitlizeDrawerData();
    string picUri = Constant.PROFILEIMAGE + Constant.localSettings.Values["profile_image"].ToString();
    imgProfilePic.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(picUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    tbDrawerMemberName.Text = Constant.localSettings.Values["name"].ToString();
 }
```

same in page2,page3... contractor ,when I am navigate from page1 to page2 and page2 to page1 (same 2 or 3 times) application exit (not crash) `has exited with code 0 (0x0)`
I have test my code in Nokia Lunia 520

Comment: Having the same problem, also using the DrawerLayout, have not found a solution yet

Comment: I have found the solution , `   this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;`

Comment: not a solution, just a workaround that will create another problems for you